# Weird overflow inside foreignObject elements

Tags: svg

I get some weird overflow whenever I want to fit an object inside `foreignObject` tag.
Take the code below. Instead of expanding to 100x100, the box expands to 120px, which is double the border width. I've tried nearly everything in my mind to counteract this effect, but nothing seems to solve the issue.

```html
<svg width="4in" height="3in" version="1.1"
 xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <foreignObject width="100" height="100">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color: #fcefa1;border:10px solid     #ff0000;"></div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

[image: Overflow problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's double the border width because you have a border on both sides, ten plus ten is twenty.  [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/xvYYk/):

```
<svg width="4in" height="3in" version="1.1"
 xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <foreignObject width="100" height="100">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color: #fcefa1;border:10px solid #ff0000; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;"></div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

The [`box-sizing` CSS property](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) lets you control what the width applies to.

Comment: Perfect! I think I lived in the SVG ecosystem for too long now :-)